# Question about Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff Formula

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-groups, matrix-equations

Let $X$, $Y$, $V$ be matrices.

$$e^{\tilde{V}}=e^{X}e^{V}e^{Y}$$

How to use the [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula) to prove the following identity?

$$\tilde{V}=V+\frac{1}{2}[V,Y-X]+\mathrm{ad}_{V/2}\coth(\mathrm{ad}_{V/2})(X+Y)+ ...,$$
where $\mathrm{ad}_{V}\cdot X=[V,X]$ is the Lie derivative.

Comment: @Cosmas Zachos Thank you for your comment. Sorry I forgot to list the reference. I just blindly copied the formula from the SUSY SUGRA book "Wess & Bagger", equation (7.21) on page 46. I'll check it again.

Comment: Indeed, the ellipses (...) in (7.18, 7.19) mean terms of higher order in $\Lambda, \Lambda'$, which I indicate in my answer. W&B *define* $\delta V$ in (7.21) to be the lowest order result in (7.19), that is they define it to be the truncation of the ellipses.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Thanks for the editing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in the comment, you really wish to show 
$$e^{\tilde{V}}=e^{X}e^{V}e^{Y}\equiv e^W e^Y\\ 
\tilde{V}=V+\frac{1}{2}[V,Y-X]+ \mathrm{ad}_{V/2}\coth(\mathrm{ad}_{V/2})(X+Y)+ O(X^2,Y^2,XY),$$
that is, all orders in V but only linear in *X,Y*. (You can tell this must be  so from special cases *X=0* or *Y=-X*.)

We'll use the standard partial CBH formulas from WP,
$$
Z= \log (e^X e^Y) = X+\frac{ \mathrm{ad}_{X}}{1-e^{-\mathrm{ad}_{X}}}~Y +O(Y^2)= X+  \mathrm{ad}_{X/2}(1+\coth\mathrm{ad}_{X/2} )~Y +O(Y^2)=   \\
= Y- \frac{ \mathrm{ad}_{Y}}{1-e^{\mathrm{ad}_{Y}}}~X +O(X^2)                 , 
$$
the second one following from the cornerstone CBH symmetry $Z(Y,X)=-Z(-X,-Y) $. We'll use this second one first, and *then* the first one.

We thus seek
$$
\tilde V= \log (  e^{V-\frac{ \mathrm{ad}_{V}}{1-e^{\mathrm{ad}_{V}}}~X +O(X^2)  } ~~e^Y  )   = W + \frac{ \mathrm{ad}_{W}}{1-e^{-\mathrm{ad}_{W}}}~Y +O(Y^2).
$$

Now, crucially, $ \mathrm{ad}_{W} \to  \mathrm{ad}_{V}$ to linear order in *X,Y*, so that 
$$
\tilde V = V-\frac{ \mathrm{ad}_{V}}{1-e^{\mathrm{ad}_{V}}}~X +O(X^2)+ \frac{ \mathrm{ad}_{V}}{1-e^{-\mathrm{ad}_{V}}}~Y +O(Y^2) +O(XY) \\
= V + \frac{1}{2} \mathrm{ad}_{V} (Y-X) + \left ( \frac{ \mathrm{ad}_{V}}{1-e^{-\mathrm{ad}_{V}}} -\mathrm{ad}_{V/2} \right )~Y +\left (-\frac{ \mathrm{ad}_{V}}{1-e^{\mathrm{ad}_{V}}}+\mathrm{ad}_{V/2}\right )X                           +O(...)
$$
$$
=  V + \frac{1}{2} [V,Y-X] + \bbox[yellow]{\mathrm{ad}_{V/2}  \coth ( \mathrm{ad}_{V/2})  ~( Y+X)      +O(...)}.
$$

Comment: Thank you very much, professor. Could you also leave a comment about equation (7.21) on page 46 of the book "Supersymmetry and Supergravity" by Wess and Bagger?

Comment: W&B define the quantity in (7.21) to be the truncation of the ellipses in (7.19), which I properly included in my standard CBH formula review (and which they attribute to Hausdorff!), but omitted from the question, raising flags. The ellipses ... are precisely these higher order terms in *X,Y*.